# How to get rows affected in a UPDATE statement by PyMySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I need to update some rows on the MySQL database by PyMYSQL and I want to know **how many rows had been changed.**

```
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect(xxxx)
cur = db.cursor()
sql = "update TABLE set A = 'abc' where B = 'def'"
cur.execute(sql, params)
db.commit()
```

Answer (score 28):

You can do this by `cursor.rowcount` after executing stage. Ff return value of this is opposite of 0 it means one or more rows are affected.

Comment: great, useful for me

Answer (score 17):

Mysql provides a special call that will help you achieve exactly that: `mysql-affected-rows`. This function is especially useful on updates as it will return only the number of rows that were affected, not the ones where the updated value was similar. Documentation is [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-affected-rows.html).

How to use this in Python? The [return](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb-1.2.2/public/MySQLdb.cursors.BaseCursor-class.html#execute) of `execute` command will return you exactly this.

```
affected_rows = cur.execute(sql, params)
```

Comment: Seems it does not work anymore using `mysql.connector`